# Is the function g continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

Using Bolzano's theorem and studying the derivative I could prove that, for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$, the equation $e^x+x^3+x+\cos x = a$ has an unique solution. Let's call it $x_a$ and define the function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ as $g(a)=x_a$, that is, the function that to each $a\in\mathbb{R}$ associates the unique solution of $e^x+x^3+x+\cos x = a$. I'm wondering if $g$ is continuous. I tried to prove by the characterization $\varepsilon-\delta$ of the continuity, but I didn't end up with something useful. Any help or advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think an easier way to state this problem is: $f(x)=e^x+x^3+x+\cos x$ is strictly monotonic and therefore has an inverse; call the inverse $g(x)$. Is $g(x)$ continuous?

Comment: Oh this way is really easy. Thank you very much!

Comment: [Inverse Function Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem)